# FPDFI - setSourceFile as string and not file

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using FPDFI to manipulate an existing PDF. I get this PDF back in the form of a base64 encoding string from an external API. I then create a PDF and then use the following code to manipulate it:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$sourceFileName = 'label.pdf';
$pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFileName);
```

Is it possible to bypass the process of creating the file and just send the base64 decoded string straight into setSourceFile, e.g:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceString(base64_encode($labelString));
```

I can't find anything in the docs.

EDIT:

I seem to have been able to solve this by using the tempnam() function in PHP:

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "ABC");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $label);
fclose($handle);
```

And then referring to $tmpfname as $sourceFileName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a [stream wrapper](http://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/#question-192) instead.